# Symfony property_path not working properly after upgrade to 2.8

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm making migration from Symfony 2.7 to 2.8.

My model has field $text that is array and has a setter:

```
public function setText(array $text)
{
    $this->$text = $text;

    return $this;
}
```

Text that i'm trying to save has two fields for different languages (FormType part bellow):

```
$builder->add('text_en', 'text', array(
    'required' => false,
    'property_path' => 'text[en]'
));
$builder->add('text_pl', 'text', array(
    'required' => false,
    'property_path' => 'text[pl]'
));
```

On Symfony 2.7 everything is ok (setter is firing once with values from both fields), but after upgrade to 2.8, setter is firing two times for each field, and result is that $text has only value from second field instead of both (second time it overrides value from field with 'en' language). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this (in case that you revert back to older Symfony version :)):

```
public function setText(array $text)
{
    foreach ($text as $key => $value) {
    $this->$text[$key] = $value;
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid this solution, but i'll use it if there will be no options left

Comment: Why? Your code forces to use that. Normally you should implement translatable entity/document instead of doing dirty not reusable forms. Imagine if you want to add additional language, you then have to change all you forms code.

Comment: Code above is simplified. I'm actually adding fields in loop.

Comment: And you tell me that you trying to avoid code that I provided - sick.